# GeoFencing enter and exit

Tags: android, gps, android-geofence

I tried using GeoFencing in Android to update some data which is based on user's current location.
After user exits a FENCE, I update the fence and set current location as center of fence.
The problem is after a while the app stops sending FENCE EXIT message forever.
I guess this is because of low accuracy location which sets a fence on a place I never was and probably I won't be in future.
What is the best way to update app data using current location of user in for example 10 min interval, but without using GPS, since GPS shows annoying indicator in status bar.
@commonsware
@pablo-baxter

Comment: There is a parmeter that defined for how long you want to keep the fence.
if you set iit to 10 min for example, after 10 minutes you won't get any updates about it anymore. did you used it by any chance ?

Comment: Where is such parameter?? @SagiMymon

Comment: look here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#setExpirationDuration(long)